# Find minimum value based on specific parameter in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write query that select the earliest hour based on AIRCRAFTREG column. When the earliest hour found, it'll be marked with '1' and the other (non first flight) with '0' in FIRST_FLIGHT column.
Here's my query:

```
select MIN(TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI')) SCHED_DEP,
       AIRCRAFTREG, 
       CASE WHEN MIN(TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI')) 
                 IN (TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')) 
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FIRST_FLIGHT
from DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS
where STATUS IN ('Scheduled') 
  and SERVICETYPE IN ('J','G') 
  and ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF_LC is not null 
  and ACTUAL_BLOCKON_LC is not null 
  and (ACTUAL_BLOCKON_LC-SCHEDULED_ARRDT_LC)*24*60 > '+000000015 00:00:00.000000000' 
  and (ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF_LC-SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC)*24*60 > '+000000015 00:00:00.000000000' 
  and TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '2018-05-02' and '2018-05-02'
group by AIRCRAFTREG, SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC
order by AIRCRAFTREG;
```

The result:

```
+----------------+-------------+--------------+
|   SCHED_DEP    | AIRCRAFTREG | FIRST_FLIGHT |
+----------------+-------------+--------------+
| 02-05-18 14:25 | PK-GAA      |            0 |
| 02-05-18 16:55 | PK-GAI      |            0 |
| 02-05-18 12:50 | PK-GAJ      |            0 |
| 02-05-18 14:40 | PK-GAJ      |            0 |
| 02-05-18 16:05 | PK-GAJ      |            0 |
+----------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Expected:

```
+----------------+-------------+--------------+
|   SCHED_DEP    | AIRCRAFTREG | FIRST_FLIGHT |
+----------------+-------------+--------------+
| 02-05-18 14:25 | PK-GAA      |            1 |
| 02-05-18 16:55 | PK-GAI      |            1 |
| 02-05-18 12:50 | PK-GAJ      |            1 |
| 02-05-18 14:40 | PK-GAJ      |            0 |
| 02-05-18 16:05 | PK-GAJ      |            0 |
+----------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need an [analytic version of MIN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions087.htm) function instead of GROUP BY query.
A simple example (demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb331/3)

```
SELECT SCHED_DEP,
       AIRCRAFTREG,
       CASE WHEN SCHED_DEP =
            min( SCHED_DEP ) OVER (partition by AIRCRAFTREG )
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as FIRST_FLIGHT
FROM Table1
-- WHERE your where conditions are here
order by AIRCRAFTREG, SCHED_DEP

|             SCHED_DEP | AIRCRAFTREG | FIRST_FLIGHT |
|-----------------------|-------------|--------------|
| 2018-02-05 14:25:00.0 |      PK-GAA |            1 |
| 2018-02-05 16:55:00.0 |      PK-GAI |            1 |
| 2018-02-05 12:50:00.0 |      PK-GAJ |            1 |
| 2018-02-05 14:40:00.0 |      PK-GAJ |            0 |
| 2018-02-05 16:05:00.0 |      PK-GAJ |            0 |
```

Comment: It works really well, thank you! I'd like to give useful vote but sadly my reputation is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

First off you have a typo, you're comparing YYYY char to YY in the select.

Second i think you would need to do a subquery in the CASE statement to find min(sched_dep) for the aircraftreg code (it'd be ugly, prob there is a better way).

Group by method doesn't allow you to scan all the other rows to compare (only the same row).